# How do find Name and Assembly js asp.net file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gzip, scriptmanager

i want active gzip for js in asp.net. i use ScriptManager and this code:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
<CompositeScript>
<Scripts>
<asp:ScriptReference  Path="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Name="MicrosoftAjax.debug.js" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.7.123, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" />
<asp:ScriptReference Name="MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.debug.js" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.7.123, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" /> 
</Scripts>
</CompositeScript>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

its working. but i have one js and do not know Name and Assembly. plase help me for find name and assembly this js file.

File:

WebResource.axd?d=qRVKOjs7_pTkijfl7uZM8g2&t=634879765642719078

Summary Code js:

```
function WebForm_PostBackOptions(eventTarget, eventArgument, validation, validationGroup, actionUrl, trackFocus, clientSubmit) {
this.eventTarget = eventTarget;
this.eventArgument = eventArgument;
this.validation = validation;
this.validationGroup = validationGroup;
this.actionUrl = actionUrl;
this.trackFocus = trackFocus;
this.clientSubmit = clientSubmit;
}
function WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(options) {
var validationResult = true;
if (options.validation) {
    if (typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
        validationResult = Page_ClientValidate(options.validationGroup);
    }
}
if (validationResult) {
    if ((typeof(options.actionUrl) != "undefined") && (options.actionUrl != null) && (options.actionUrl.length > 0)) {
        theForm.action = options.actionUrl;
    }
    if (options.trackFocus) {
        var lastFocus = theForm.elements["__LASTFOCUS"];
        if ((typeof(lastFocus) != "undefined") && (lastFocus != null)) {
            if (typeof(document.activeElement) == "undefined") {
                lastFocus.value = options.eventTarget;
            }
            else {
                var active = document.activeElement;
                if ((typeof(active) != "undefined") && (active != null)) {
                    if ((typeof(active.id) != "undefined") && (active.id != null) && (active.id.length > 0)) {
                        lastFocus.value = active.id;
                    }
                    else if (typeof(active.name) != "undefined") {
                        lastFocus.value = active.name;
                    }
                }
            }
.
.
.
```

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, there's nothing in the latest version of the framework that would compress the resources served by `WebResource.axd`. You will have to do it yourself.

The good news is that someone else already did the work. See here:

http://madskristensen.net/post/Optimize-WebResourceaxd-and-ScriptResourceaxd.aspx

Comment: i use this, but error: Microsoft JScript runtime error: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load. / i use web application and copy ScriptCompressor.cs in folder.